# Proving a subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that A ⊂ B if and only if, A ∩ B = A

This seems straightforward to understand and then explain in words, as the two statements are equivalent, but I don't understand how I would correctly explain this in a formal sense?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't come across that in my search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** to show that $X=Y$ you have to show both inclusions: $X\subset Y$ and $Y\subset X$.